# iOS App acting differently after archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, asihttprequest, objective-c-blocks

while running the app straight from xcode on my phone everything runs great.
after archiving it and running it as an archive the app acts differently and doesn't behave as expected. this is the part where an asihttprequest never ends when running from an archive.
i'll be happy for some help.

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

[tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"uiAction"
                    withAction:@"station pressed"
                     withLabel:@"Station number"
                     withValue:num];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/servlet?stationId=%d",    [num intValue]]];

__weak ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSLog(@"0");

[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    @try {
        NSLog(@"1");
        StopParser *stop = [[StopParser alloc]init];
                    NSLog(@"2");
        timesArray = [stop getStationsListfromString:[request responseString]];
                    NSLog(@"3");
        [stView.downlodingLabel setHidden:YES];
        [stView.downloadingIndicator setHidden:YES];
        [stView.tableview reloadData];
        [stView.tableview setHidden:NO];


    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
                    NSLog(@"4");
        [stView.downloadingIndicator setHidden:YES];
        [stView.downlodingLabel setHidden:NO];
        [stView.downlodingLabel setText:@"נא לנסות מאוחר יותר"];
        [stView.tableview setHidden:YES];

    }
    @finally {
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }

}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
                NSLog(@"5");
    [stView.downloadingIndicator setHidden:YES];
    [stView.downlodingLabel setHidden:NO];
    [stView.downlodingLabel setText:@"נא לנסות מאוחר יותר"];
    [stView.tableview setHidden:YES];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];

}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `__weak` is your problem. Use `__block` instead.

No strong reference is saved for `request`, so it is released.

[ARC Introduces New Lifetime Qualifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4)

- `__weak` specifies a reference that does not keep the referenced object alive. A weak reference is set to nil when there are no strong references to the object.

[The __block Storage Type](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6)

`__block` variables live in storage that is shared between the lexical scope of the variable and all blocks and block copies declared or created within the variable’s lexical scope. Thus, the storage will survive the destruction of the stack frame if any copies of the blocks declared within the frame survive beyond the end of the frame (for example, by being enqueued somewhere for later execution). Multiple blocks in a given lexical scope can simultaneously use a shared variable.

---

**UPDATE**

to be clear my suggestion is to replace:

```
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

with:

```
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

This should not cause a retain cycle.

Comment: i used this and it works. any problems with this solution?
ASIHTTPRequest *_request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *request = _request;

Comment: by the way, when im using your solution it says "Capturing 'request' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle

Answer (score 0):

Typically archive has a different build configuration than the debug one which is more common to run in the simulator. Make sure you are testing the same configuration both ways. It could be something is different between each build.

We use debug, ad-hoc and release build configurations. The latter two are used for archiving. ad-hoc can be built and run from Xcode directly so that an archive from that configuration should be identical.